# How to pass url to reducer in a correct way?

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I have created my first slice:

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'axios';

const initialState = {
    current: null,
    value: [],
    status: 'idle',
    error: null,
};

export const fetchLists = createAsyncThunk(
    'list/fetchLists',
    async () => {
        const response = await axios.get('/api/data');
        return response.data;
    },
);
...

export const listSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'list',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
    ....
    },

    extraReducers: {
    ...
    }
    ....
```

The pint is I do not want to have hardcoded url in the slice.
On the other hand, I do not want to pass it every time I call dispatch().

What is the correct way to replace the path (literal) by a variable in the slice?

Answer (score 0):

If you use create-react-app, you can use [environment variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) :

```
process.env.REACT_APP_WEBSERVICE_URL
```

that are replaced at build time,
in your .env file you can add it like this

```
REACT_APP_WEBSERVICE_URL="example.com"
```

if you do not use cra you can just add the [dotenv package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) manually

EDIT: if you get the base url during runtime, you can store it in another redux slice and get it like this with [createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk):

```
export const fetchLists = createAsyncThunk(
    'list/fetchLists',
    async (arg, thunkAPI) => {
        const baseUrl = thunkAPI.getState().sliceName.baseURL;
        const response = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/data`);
        return response.data;
    },
);
```

or you could store it anywhere actually, like localStorage, sessionStorage, cookies

Comment: Good idea! Unfortunately for some reasons I do not know the base url at the build time and it is passed from backend as root component's parameter :(